# What is a compatible data type for 'specific' date and time?

Tags: postgresql, csv, import, transportation

I need to import CSV file into PostgreSQL, but I got an error on time column which has data like this:

*11/1/2016 12:00:00 AM*

I tried to make column and assign 'timestamp' data type, but it's just not working.
Can anyone resolve this problem?

Comment: Each RDBMS generally supports several flavors of time columns. You really ought to evaluate all those available for your own needs, but those needs should probably include the supported types permitted by your GIS software (which you don't mention).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TO_TIMESTAMP(timestamp, format).

So first import as a sting then you can convert it:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP('11/1/2016 12:00:00 AM', 'FMDD/FMMM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')
```

Check out:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-formatting.html